# C# checking if more files have one of more of these strings

Tags: c#

it's me again , your boi...
Stuck with another problem I didn't find anywhere else strangely...
This is the code I possess in order to check if files in a directory and subdirectiories have a certain string. If they do, I'll add a string at the bottom of the file...
I followed for most part the documentation on Microsoft Docs.

```
public class OFiles
{
    public string PathProgetto
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Change()
    {

        try
        {
            string docPath = PathProject;

            var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(docPath, "*.h", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                        where line.Contains("String I want")
                       // where line.Contains("Other String I want")
                       // where line.Contains("Another String I want")

                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                            Line = line
                        };

            System.Collections.ArrayList arr = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                arr.Add(f.File.ToString());

            }
            string sNuovaRiga = "This One";
            foreach (var s in arr)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(s.ToString(), "\r\n" + sNuovaRiga);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{files.Count().ToString()} files found and modified.");
        }

        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException pathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pathEx.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

You'll notice that there are other strings I want my program to check. The problem is that I have no idea how to do it, I only know that the way I did it I cannot do it with another WHERE so I'm asking here. Ask me anything unclear and thanks in advance

Comment: Look into using the `||` (OR) operator...

Comment: @elgonzo Could I integrate it into the code I made?

Comment: [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches)

Comment: @Simone, sure you can...

Comment: @elgonzo as expected, you were right, using `where line.Contains("String I want")||line.Contains("Other String I want")` does the trick. However I opted to another way and that is putting every string into an array and then looping with a foreach. If you want to add your answer tho, I can select it as the best... I don't know how this works, I just wanted to give you point for the tip

Comment: If you choose to put the strings in some collection, i suggest to use a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array. Not only is the lookup rather simple: `myHashSet.Contains(someString)` (well, you could do the same with an array  too), but lookups in HashSets are rather fast, too...

Comment: @elgonzo would it also improve performance?

Comment: Technically, yes. Is the performance difference observable? Perhaps. Is the performance difference significant in any way? Impossible to tell without being able to judge or know the runtime behavior of your program...

Comment: @elgonzo understood. If I may bother you a little further, how do I mark this question as closed? Do I delete it? Also, I noticed I have 2 negative votes on this question. In your opinion, could it be for the content of this question, the way I phrased it or maybe it's a different reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to close this question, so I'll just answer it.
As @elgonzo suggested, in this particular all I had to do was putting `||` when I had to choose between the strings.